# Having Trouble Importing MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, import, dump

Whenever I try to import a database I keep getting a wall of text and I have no clue what to do with it. I have googled around and everywhere I go says to do the following:

```
mysqlimport -u USERNAMEHERE -pPASSWORD DATABASENAMEHERE < path/to/dbdump.sql
```

or

```
mysql -u USERNAMEHERE -pPASSWORD DATABASENAMEHERE < path/to/dbdump.sql
```

However when I try to use it all I get is this:

[image: screenshot]

```
Checklist:  
 File exists: yes  
 Username is correct: yes  
 DB name is correct: yes  
 Path to file is correct: yes
 Password is correct: yes
```

I can dump the database without a problem but I just cant restore it and it contains some really important information....

EDIT:

Also im using ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit with MYSQL ver 3.7 Distrib 5.5.41, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)

Comment: do you have a space character after -p option? there should be no space between -p option and the password

Comment: Your second example (using `mysql`) worked for me. Try it again and then [edit] your question to show the exact error message you get. (Please copy and paste it into the question as text, not as a screenshot.)

Comment: What you are getting in your screenshot for mysqlimport is a usage help message, because there is no "<" operator in the command [see docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html).
mysql should work for you also

Comment: When trying example two I get:  ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqlimport  Ver 3.7 Distrib 5.5.41, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
Copyright (c)' at line 1

Comment: can you post the first line(s) of your dump file?

Comment: It sounds like you have some "junk" at the beginning of your .sql file. A proper `mysqldump` of a database should look something like [this](http://pastebin.com/hkUW9tny).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`--password=YourPassword`

And you should be able to use mysql. The mysqlimport is for imported teb-delimited text files and such as that.

Comment: same wall of text as the original :(

Answer (score 0):

Google for "BigDump"

It's a light weight, single page PHP script. You download it, put your database info in the source, then upload it to your server.

It will handle your imports that are too big for phpMyAdmin by uploading them in pieces.

Comment: ill look into it however I dumped it using the mysqldump instead of phpmyadmin will that affect it?

Comment: @mushi1996 Doesn't matter. How do you think phpMyAdmin does it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you can try to add **host**:

```
mysql -hHost -uUser -pPass -DBase < dumpFile.sql
```

it works for me everytime...

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqlimport -u USERNAMEHERE -pPASSWORD DATABASENAMEHERE < path/to/dbdump.sql
```

This is wrong usage for `mysqlimport`. The error message shows you the proper usage:

> Usage: mysqlimport [OPTIONS] database textfile...

You name the text file(s) as arguments, not as standard input redirection as with the usage of the `mysql` client.

Also, `mysqlimport` cannot read an .sql file, it reads one or more text files in CSV format. The name of the file(s) must be the names of the corresponding tables to load data into. Please read the [mysqlimport documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html) before attempting to use this tool.

```
mysql -u USERNAMEHERE -pPASSWORD DATABASENAMEHERE < path/to/dbdump.sql
```

This is correct usage for reading an .sql file, but the error you described indicates that the file doesn't contain an SQL script:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqlimport Ver 3.7 Distrib 5.5.41, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) Copyright (c)' at line 1

It seems like the file contains the *output* of running the mysqlimport command. I suspect that you got confused about `<` versus `>`, and did this:

```
mysqlimport -u USERNAMEHERE -pPASSWORD DATABASENAMEHERE > path/to/dbdump.sql
```

If you did this, then unfortunately your dump file has been overwritten by that command, and the contents replaced with the output errors from your mysqlimport command. You should check the size and contents of that file and see.

```
ls -l /home/minecraft/MySQLBackup/infinity_prism_Jun_05_2015_20_01.sql
less /home/minecraft/MySQLBackup/infinity_prism_Jun_05_2015_20_01.sql
```

You should search your shell history to see what commands you ran:

```
history | grep infinity_prism
```

If this is what happened, then your data backup has been clobbered. You'll have to get a new data backup from the original database, if you still have it.

If you clobbered your backup and you don't still have the original database to create a new backup from, then I'm terribly sorry, but your data is gone.

Comment: If your data is truly gone, you will probably experience the [five stages of grief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCbler-Ross_model).